# C, calling linked list function from another file

Tags: c, linked-list

I have two files, list_funcs.c and list_mgr.c . List_funcs.c has a function to insert a node into a linked list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data_node {
char name [25];
int data;
struct data_node *next;
};

struct data_node * insert (struct data_node **p_first, int elem) {

struct data_node *new_node, *prev, *current;
current=*p_first;
while (current != NULL && elem > current->data) {
   prev=current;
   current=current->next;
} /* end while */
/* current now points to position *before* which we need to insert */
new_node = (struct data_node *) malloc(sizeof(struct data_node));
new_node->data=elem;

new_node->next=current;
if ( current == *p_first ) /* insert before 1st element */
   *p_first=new_node; 
else                       /* now insert before current */
   prev->next=new_node;
/* end if current == *p_first */
return new_node;
};
```

now I am trying to call this function from list_mgr.c like so, but getting error "too few arguments to function 'insert' ":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list_funcs.h"
int main (void) {
struct data_node *first, *new_node, *ptr;
printf("Insert first node into list\n");
first=ptr=insert(&first, 5);
strcpy(ptr->name,"Alexander");
return 0;
}
```

Why am I getting the "too few arguments" error and how can I call it correctly?

The header list_func.h contains:

```
#define STRINGMAX 25
struct data_node {
char name [STRINGMAX];
int data;
struct data_node *next;
};
struct data_node * insert (struct data_node **, int, char *);
```

Comment: You need to initialize `first` in `main()`, but that's not the compilation problem.

Comment: insert `inlcude "list_funcs.h"` in the list_funcs.c file, than the compiler will explain what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition of `insert` looks like this:

```
struct data_node * insert (struct data_node **p_first, int elem)
```

But the declaration in the header looks like this:

```
struct data_node * insert (struct data_node **, int, char *);
```

Note the `char *` there at the end.  You probably want to delete that to make it match.

Answer (score 4):

There are three arguments to the function, and you're only passing the first two.

```
struct data_node * insert (struct data_node **, int, char *);
```

Requires you to pass a pointer to a `data_node*`, then an `int`, and finally a `char*` type.

Confusingly enough, your definition of the function doesn't match the declaration either, with the last `char*` being omitted in the definition.

Comment: Well, sort of.  The forward declaration doesn't match the implementation, which is the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your function prototype in `list_func.h` has an extra argument:

```
struct data_node * insert (struct data_node **, int, char *);
/*                one of these doesn't belong:  ^    ^ */
```

So the function definition in `list_mgr.c` and the call in `list_funcs.c` match, the prototype in `list_func.h` doesn't.